# Converting Printable to PDF

Tags: java, image, pdf, printing

I am working on a user story that asks to be able to print all the existing print out as PDFs too. To do this I am rendering the `java.awt.Printable` to a `BufferedImage` and putting this image into a PDF using Apache's PDFBox but I am having a couple of issues using this method:

- If I use `PDJPeg` the image becomes blurry.
- If I use `PDPixelMap` the resulting PDF is completely black.

The only other way I can think of is to make a interface, i.e. `Printer`, and then making two subclasses i.e. `PhysicalPrinter` and `PDFPrinter` but this would require that I reimplement all existing `java.awt.Printable`s to use this new interface.

Here is a SSCCE of my current print to PDF method:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg;

public class Printer {
    private Printer() {}
    public static boolean printToPDF(String file, Printable printable) {
        try {
            PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
            PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
            int width = (int)(pageFormat.getWidth());
            int height = (int)(pageFormat.getHeight());

            int currentPage = 0;
            while(true) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                                                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 12));

                if(printable.print(g2d, pageFormat, currentPage) == Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE) {
                    break;
                }
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));

                PDPage page = new PDPage();
                doc.addPage(page);

                PDJpeg img = new PDJpeg(doc, image); //Blurry
                //PDPixelMap img = new PDPixelMap(doc, image); //Black
                PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                content.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                content.close();

                ++currentPage;
            }

            doc.save(file);
            doc.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printable printable = new Printable() {
            @Override
            public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int index) 
            throws PrinterException {
                if(index > 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                Random rand = new Random();

                for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
                    int x = rand.nextInt((int)pf.getImageableWidth());
                    int y = rand.nextInt((int)pf.getImageableHeight());

                    g2d.drawString("Test", x, y);
                }

                return PAGE_EXISTS;
            }
        };

        printToPDF("Test.pdf", printable);
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

I managed to solved the black `PDPixelMap`, it was down to the `BUfferedImage` using the wrong image type. I changed it from `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` to `BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR`. Unfortunately the resultant PDF is still blurry.

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the upcoming 1.8.5 version, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2030 . It is already fixed in the 2.0 version (which has a different API), see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1990 . You can get both from svn.

Answer (score 0):

I think two frameworks that might help you are [IText](http://itextpdf.com/) and [PDFRenderer](https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer/downloads). IText is free up to version 4.2 (if I remember correctly) and PDFRenderer is LGPL 2.1 licence. For examples it's best to look at the tutorials, which are plenty on the web. I think both are viable solutions for what you want to accomplish. I personally use PDFRenderer.

Comment: The documentation on PDFRenderer seems lacking (non-existant?) and the IText license for the free version requires the disclosure of the source code for projects that use it, from my understanding.

Comment: I will look at the IText license again, but if you just google for PDFRenderer and tutorial or example you will find some stuff!